# How to change horizontal spacing in arrays?

Tags: support, mathjax

$$
\begin{array}{lcr}
& \text{A} & \\[-0.1cm]
& | & \\[-0.1cm]
\text{C} & \text{B} & \text{D} \\[-0.1cm]
& | & \\[-0.1cm]
& \text{E} & \\
\end{array}
$$
How do I edit the spacing between $\text{C}$ and $\text{B}$ (as well as  $\text{B}$ and $\text{D}$)? In $\LaTeX$, one can do it by following [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103508/adjusting-space-between-array-rows-and-columns), but it does not work for MathJax. Any ideas on how to edit the array horizontal spacing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method feels kinda "hacky," but you could use [LaTeX math mode spacing commands](https://texblog.org/2014/04/09/whitespace-in-math-mode/) like `\,`, `\:`, `\;`, `\enspace`, `\quad` or `\qquad` within the cells of the array. Right click on the diagram below and select `Show Math As -> TeX Commands` to see what I mean.

\begin{array}{lcr}
& \text{A} & \\[-0.1cm]
& | & \\[-0.1cm]
\text{C}\quad & \text{B} & \quad\text{D} \\[-0.1cm]
& | & \\[-0.1cm]
& \text{E} & \\
\end{array}

But of course this would be a burden to do manually for larger arrays.

Comment: What about in case you want to shorten the spacing?

Comment: @SiddharthVenu there's another spacing command `\!` that creates a negative thin space. But it's pretty thin. You'd have to add a bunch of those to get any dramatic effect.

Comment: I guess I will have to use it even though it is clumsy. Thank you!

Comment: Another "clumsy" technique is to create alternating array entries with "phantom" characters with specified horizontal and/or vertical spacing.  See [How do I create an invisible character?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4519/how-do-i-create-an-invisible-character)  These work for me in MathJax.

Answer (score 3):

An easier way to do this is to use `\hspace` as follows:

```
\begin{array}{lcr}
  & \text{A} & \\[-0.1cm]
  & | & \\[-0.1cm]
  \text{C} \hspace{0.9cm}& \text{B} &\hspace{0.9cm} \text{D} \\[-0.1cm]
  & | & \\[-0.1cm]
  & \text{E} & \\
\end{array}`
```

gives

\begin{array}{lcr}
& \text{A} & \\[-0.1cm]
& | & \\[-0.1cm]
\text{C} \hspace{0.9cm}& \text{B} &\hspace{0.9cm} \text{D} \\[-0.1cm]
& | & \\[-0.1cm]
& \text{E} & \\
\end{array}